# ExpressJS, Nodester, template rendering paths?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I wrote a simple expressjs app that runs just fine locally, and even on no.de, but on Nodester when I access http://myapp.nodester.com/ I get an `Internal Server Error` and the logs say

```
Error: failed to locate view "home"
    at Function.compile (/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:58:15)
    at ServerResponse._render (/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:416:18)
    at ServerResponse.render (/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:317:17)
    at Router.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:32:6)
    at done (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:250:22)
    at middleware (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:244:9)
    at param (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:227:11)
    at pass (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:232:6)
    at Router._dispatch (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:255:4)
    at Object.handle (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:45:10)

Error: failed to locate view "home"
    at Function.compile (/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:58:15)
    at ServerResponse._render (/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:416:18)
    at ServerResponse.render (/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:317:17)
    at Router.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:32:6)
    at done (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:250:22)
    at middleware (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:244:9)
    at param (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:227:11)
    at pass (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:232:6)
    at Router._dispatch (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:255:4)
    at Object.handle (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:45:10)
```

Then through the fs module I tried to see why it was not there, and an `fs.readdir('.',function(error,files){console.log(files)})` returned this:

```
[ '.nodester',
  'app',
  'node_modules',
  'usr',
  'lib64',
  'sbin',
  'etc',
  'dev',
  'proc',
  'home',
  'bin',
  'lib',
  'root',
  '.PKGINFO',
  '.INSTALL' ]
```

And I also found out that all the files I `git push`ed are inside the `apps` directory.

Does this mean I must tell express the right path where my `views` folder is ? How can I do this ? (I only know how to tell it to render a file in an absolute path).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup views dir manually using built-in variable `__dirname`:

```
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();
app.configure(function(){
        ...
        app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
        app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

Try to generate application skeleton using `express` comman-line tool (it's accessible, if you install last express version from npm). It generates good starting point for you.